# How to get UserPrincipal using Angular frontend, Spring REST backend, and CAS (web.xml)?

Tags: angular, spring, rest, cas

Is it possible to get username/UserPrincipal/uid from CAS in Angular not using Spring Security?  We are trying to use our normal web.xml file to connect to CAS (which is working).  The problem is since we're not using Spring Security, I don't know if it's possible to pass username and roles into Angular.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't access backend variables directly from your front-end. Create a rest endpoint that returns what you want and call that instead.

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access server-side variables from client code. What you should do is make an endpoint that returns the current user info:

`GET`: `/current-user`

or a common pattern

`GET`: `/me`

Assuming you are working with cookies or jwt, the idea of the rest endpoint is to validate that cookie/jwt and then look the user up by it's identifier and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Created a rest endpoint as mwilson suggested.  It works!